# How to CR to display multiple value from dataset as edited from runtime

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

1.I set CR to connected with Dataset with 1 Datatable with 3 column.
2.I design report with 3 column of Datatable.
3.I have the data in Datagridview from DataBase.
4.At runtime,before display the report,I tranfer data from datagridview to the Datatable with many row data.
**The problem is when report is display,the values are not show all data. It just show only 1 data/1 row for all column.**
Would you recommend what I could do?

This is my code

```
Sub CreateSideView
    Dim arSpec(), arName(), arResult() As String
    With dgvMain
        Dim iRow As Integer = .CurrentRow.Index
        arName = .Item("alltestname", iRow).Value.ToString.Split(",")
        arSpec = .Item("alltestspec", iRow).Value.ToString.Split(",")
        arResult = .Item("alltestresult", iRow).Value.ToString.Split(",")          
    End With

    Dim dtbCOA As New dtsCOA.dtbCOADataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow
    For i = 0 To UBound(arName)
        dr = dtbCOA.NewRow
        dr("CoaName") = arName(i)
        dr("CoaSpec") = arSpec(i)
        dr("CoaResult") = arResult(i)        
        dtbCOA.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
    Dim dtbFinalCOA As DataTable = dtbCOA
    Dim Rpt As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    Rpt = New crpCOA1   
    Rpt.Database.Tables("dtbCOA").SetDataSource(dtbFinalCOA )       
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Rpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(2)

End Sub
```

Some of code of fill to Datagridview.

```
'read database to array
cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select a.*,b.Unit bUnit from RepTestItem a left join LabTestItem b " & _
    "on a.LabID = b.ID where " & _
    "a.ID in('" & RptTestID & "')", connCOA)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
Do While dr.Read
    arName(Array.IndexOf(arRptTestID, dr("ID"))) = _CNullToEmpty(dr("Name"))
    arSpec(Array.IndexOf(arRptTestID, dr("ID"))) = _CNullToEmpty(dr("Spec").ToString.Replace(",", "*"))
    arLabTestID(Array.IndexOf(arRptTestID, dr("ID"))) = _CNullToEmpty(dr("LabID"))
    arResult(Array.IndexOf(arRptTestID, dr("ID"))) = dr("FixVal")
Loop
dr.Close()

'Send values from array to Datagridview
For j = 0 To UBound(arRptTestID)
    .Item("alltestname", i).Value &= arName(j) & ","
    .Item("alltestspec", i).Value &= arSpec(j) & ","
    .Item("alltestresult", i).Value &= arResult(j) & ","
Next
```

Comment: With dgvMain is only processing one row.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question? If there is repeated comma delimited data in a single column requiring a .Split the database design might need work.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: How is your DataGridView filled originally?

Comment: @Mary , Your method make 102 error about string convert. Are you sure I must follow you to edit all error.

Comment: i update question  about Datagridview filling

Comment: this is sample value in dgv : _Description,Identification,Maltitol,Lead,Nickel,Other Hydrogenated Saccharides_  and  _Pass,0.000 %,Pass,99.7675 %,<0.5 ppm,<5 ppm,Pass_

Comment: I don't see a DataGridView being filled anywhere.

Comment: Please add the sample data to your question so I can read it. There are ways to format so it appears in columns. Right now I can't determine what is a column title and what is data. Where did the column headings get set?